# How to concatenate a string with multiple quote escapes

Tags: c#

Notice this question is related to:
[Compose GraphQL for monday.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63668337/compose-graphql-for-monday-com/63669269#63669269)

But this question only focus on the concatenation part.

I have following string:

```
var query = @"{""query"": ""mutation {create_item(board_id: 111, group_id:\""new_group\"", item_name: \""adding works\"", column_values: \"" {\\\""long_text\\\"": { \\\""text\\\"": \\\""Sample text\\\""}} \"") {id}  }"" }";
```

I want to build this string dynamically. But I don't know to.

I tried:

```
var query = @"{""query"": ""mutation {create_item(board_id: 111, group_id:\""new_group\"", item_name: \""adding works\"", column_values: \"" {\\\""long_text\\\"": { \\\""text\\\"": \\\"""+"SOME TEXT HERE"+"\\\""}} \"") {id}  }"" }";
```

Is there some guideline to concatenate strings with so many escapes?

Comment: You need to include the `@` before each of the strings you concatenate together, or at least the ones that have backslashes that should not be escape sequences and double quotes escaped by another double quote.

Comment: The guideline is: "carefully".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating two strings with escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832281/concatenating-two-strings-with-escape-sequences) this explains what you need.

Comment: Not really. Normally it is no deal concatenate strings. I also tried with @. As an example I tried:  { \\\""text\\\"": \\\"""+@""+"\\\""}} but compiler fails.

Comment: I am not sure from your example but it looks like you are storing data in a JSON format. The normal way to handle that is to define a class to represent the data then use a tool to serialize it into a JSON string (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net) or [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345382/convert-object-to-json-string-in-c-sharp))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real guideline except that you need to prefix all strings with the [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) character (`@`) if they have escape characters that you want to include as part of the string (you are missing one in front of the last string in the example from the question):

```
var query1 = @"{""query"": ""mutation {create_item(board_id: 111, group_id:\""new_group\"", item_name: \""adding works\"", column_values: \"" {\\\""long_text\\\"": { \\\""text\\\"": \\\""" 
    + "SOME TEXT HERE" 
    + @"\\\""}} \"") {id}  }"" }";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot appreciated. I had misplaced my @.